# How many collisions are possible to eradicate all already existing satellites?

Tags: artificial-satellite, orbit

If earth lost all contact with satellites, how many collisions would it take to be left with 0 satellites orbiting in their normal path?

Deep-space objects are not considered like James Web Telescope.

Comment: A satellite on a low orbit of about 400 km height is no danger for satellites for in a much higher orbit, for instance GEO, a circular geosynchronous orbit 35,786 km above the surface of Earth.

Comment: There is a boring math answer here of 'number of collisions = number of satellites/2'. Is the intention to ask 'how many collisions before all in use orbits are in danger?'. Also as noted by Uwe, orbits matter, the number of collisions before the James Web Telescope in endangers is very very high given it lives in a single out well out from Earth. Recommend editing to place an altitude limit of either LEO or GEO to keep deep space objects out of the maths.

Comment: This really isn't a question about Space Exploration. It, like some of your others, seem to be focused on speculative fiction. Please re-read our [about] and [ask] pages.

Comment: Hi @RoryAlsop where do you suggest migrating these questions? can you help please, thanks in advance.

Comment: Your best bet is Worldbuilding.SE, however as they stand, your questions don't meet site requirements so would be rejected. I suggest spending time there, lurk and see what questions are well received, thoroughly read their site guidelines and be responsive to comments asking for clarity, detail etc.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is based other questions by OP that seem to indicates interest in how to achieve a worst case [Kesler syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kessler_syndrome) quickly for a work of fiction.

Satellites orbit at a range of altitudes and [inclinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_inclination)

[image]

Animated version at source [here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b4/Comparison_satellite_navigation_orbits.svg)

In general collisions can be expected to remove energy so produce debris in lower orbits rather than higher, so events in LEO cannot sensibly impacts MEO/GEO orbits. Further it is high crossing inclination that produce the absurdly high collision energy, so dead GEO satellites all in the same 0(ish) inclination orbit will tend to only have car highway speed collisions rather than faster than bullet collisions possible in LEO when [equatorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near-equatorial_orbit#Non-inclined_orbit) and [polar orbits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun-synchronous_orbit) intersect at several kilometers a second.

There is also just plain more volume in GEO/MEO space for debris to be in without colliding.

LEO Space is already busy enough that collision avoidance is ongoing, with this [2017 discussion](https://www.esa.int/Enabling_Support/Operations/Anatomy_of_a_debris_incident) mentioning a 3 satellite constellation having several hundred alerts of which 10 were potential collisions each year, making a potential collision every 110 days per satellite. This suggests that if all control was lost to the [3000 LEO satellites](https://dewesoft.com/daq/every-satellite-orbiting-earth-and-who-owns-them) that there would be 24 potential collisions per day. Even allowing for fact that 'potential collision' just means needing study rather than a certain hit this suggests collisions will start within days with each hit multiplying the risk of impacts to remaining intact satellites in LEO.

This however does nothing much to MEO and GEO orbits with fewer objects and more volume to hide in probably preventing a cascade, unless things got unlucky.

To ensure that unlucky happens, large amounts of 'stuff' in a highly elliptical orbit crossing GEO is needed. A possible example being a 100+ tonne transfer to the moon or mars loosing integrity during departure burn, such that the debris cloud  rises through GEO before crossing back down close to the original LEO parking orbit. Several thousand chunks doing this would produce a very complicated collision avoidance problem, though even with a truly absurd amount of debris it will take time to cascade GEO and MEO.

100 tonnes turned into 10g chunks gets 10 million objects, but spread them into a cube on a 10 meter spacing you are still only 'clearing' a volume two kilometers on a side each orbit, which given a LEO orbit is 44,000 kilometers long has a reasonable probability of a miss per orbit ~20 hour orbit, and out at GEO the 263 thousand kilometer orbit distance leaves hundreds of kilometers for the [565 GEO](https://dewesoft.com/daq/every-satellite-orbiting-earth-and-who-owns-them) satellites to have low hit probabilities in, at least for the days/weeks timeframe.

Without some catastrophic inciting event or malicious intent it seems unlikely a basic communications loss can cause destruction of all satellites out to GEO through collisions.